# Ember disabled button

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm having an issue with embers bind-attr on the 'disabled' attribute on a button. Basically I can't get it to not disable my button.

isCancelled is a boolean in my model, according to [this](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/binding-element-attributes/) it should make 'disabled' appear and disappear inside the rendered tag.

Button looks like:

```
<button {{action "cancel" provisioning}} {{bind-attr disabled="isCancelled"}}>
```

It always renders the 'disabled' attribute.

I made a simple check to debug it. It looks like this:

```
isCancelled: {{isCancelled}}
```

It renders like: isCancelled: false

I'm using Ember 1.12.0

Answer (score 18):

The bind-attr syntax is deprecated:

```
<button {{action "cancel" provisioning}} disabled={{isCancelled}}>
```

And in your case you are passing a string not the `isCancelled` property therefore it is always true,  `{{bind-attr disabled=isCancelled}}>` would work.

Comment: I tried with `{{bind-attr disabled=isCancelled}}` also. Same result. But I will try `disabled={{isCancelled}}` tomorrow.

Comment: `disabled={{isCancelled}}` had same result. Tag is rendered with 'disabled' attribute.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that if isCancelled is false, it will still render the disabled tag.

Make sure isCancelled is either TRUE or NULL. Only when it is null, 'disabled' won't be rendered

Comment: I do not believe this is true. I never fixed this problem directly, but I got rid of it eventually after changing a lot of code and bumping to Ember 2.0.

Comment: It is the case in Ember 2.0. I encountered this a few weeks ago.

Other references:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358020/ember-htmlbars-boolean-bound-attributes-are-not-booleans

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10976

Comment: This works, while `return false` does not:

`<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" {{action 'confirm'}} disabled={{disableAddPerson}}>Toevoegen</button>`

`disableAddPerson: function() {
        var chosenPerson = this.get("chosenPerson");
        if (chosenPerson == null || this.get("type") == null || this.get("function") == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return null;
    }.property("chosenPerson", "function", "type")`

Comment: +1 @ThomasStubbe is correct. I'm not sure why it had -1 on it. @Osthekake even in 2.x this works. You can return boolean values to a computed property `submitIsDisabled` and then inside your handlebars templates just do `<button disabled={{if submitIsDisabled true null}}>...</button>` that way you get the benefit of the working disabled property toggle and your JavaScript functions may still return any truthy or falsey values rather than force you to return `null`. [Here's an Ember Twiddle demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/78532bea9f9e51f647e5cd0b64da749c?openFiles=controllers.application.js)

Comment: @OnethingSimple I believe you are missing the point. The documentation states that disabled={{attribute}} should work as expected with values that are false, and not necessarily null. Saying that even in 2.x it works is also a mute point, since in 2.x it works as expected anyway, i.e. not rendering the 'disabled' attribute if the value given is false. The entire disabled={{attribute}} syntax didn't exist in earlier versions, hence why I used {{bind-attr in my original example.

Comment: @Osthekake You are right about the problem. This is a bug in Ember, and the docs say otherwise. However, it is basic HTML behavior: see [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp). I was merely pointing out what the problem was and how to fix it. But the comment you gave 'I do not believe this is true' was very unfriendly if you haven't test it ;)

Comment: @Osthekake I'll agree, I missed the point a bit focusing more towards this single solution and comments, therein ignoring the larger picture and its relationship to the actual question/situation. I will rescind my original comment. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Using Ember 3 and Bootstrap 4, I just tried to set `disabled=true` or `disabled=false` on a button and this had no effect.; You should just use `disabled` as Bootstrap suggests for disabled items: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#disabled-items